# How do i bind JSON Object to form fields to edit them?

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

I am trying to add an edit button to enable the user to edit table data using the form they use to submit new data.

How do I bind the JSON object data to the form elements?

My typescript;

```
edit(id){

   this.http.get('api/getRequest.php?section=getProductSetupById&id='+ id)
       .map((response: any = Response) => <EditProduct[]> response.json()[0])
       .subscribe(editProduct => this.editProducts= editProduct);

}
```

One of My ionic 2 form elements.

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label for="company">Company:</ion-label>
   <ion-input formControlName="company" type="text" ngModel name="company" id="company"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
```

I'm still relatively new to Angular and Ionic 2. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to follow, but I think your asking how to use Angular's double binding syntax. I assume your "editProduct" object has a field called "Company" on it?

in this case you could do this

In your module you will need to import{ FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms'

Then whenever your editProduct.Company changes in typescript, the input will update, and whenever the input updates your editProduct.Company will update too.

This is template driven binding. Its the easiest way to start with forms in Angular I think!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this approach:

Define setter and getter for the JSON Input field like this in typescript component:

```
public jsonArray;

get someFunction() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.jsonArray, null, 2);
}

set someFunction(value) {
    try {
        this.jsonArray= JSON.parse(value);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    };
}
```

And In HTML part bind it like this:

```
<textarea class="" id="json-input" placeholder="Paste json here." [(ngModel)]="someFunction">
```

You can Modify it according to Ionic, I don't have experience in Ionic.
Hope This helps.